# bash: Printf splitting output of `uptime` into multiple lines

Tags: bash, printf, uptime

I have a very simple script that tries to get the uptime of the local device and print it out as a string.  Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
UPTIME=$(uptime -p)
printf "Uptime: %s\n" $UPTIME
```

The output is:

```
meatcram@digest01:~$ bash test.sh 
Uptime: up
Uptime: 1
Uptime: week,
Uptime: 3
Uptime: days,
Uptime: 1
Uptime: hour,
Uptime: 13
Uptime: minutes
```

If I run the `uptime -p` command from the command line, the output looks like a normal text string:

```
meatcram@digest01:~$ uptime -p
up 1 week, 3 days, 1 hour, 17 minutes
```

What gives?

Comment: Quote your variable

Comment: wow. that was it, thanks.  I should just walk away from the keyboard now.  do you want to post as an answer so I can mark solved?

Comment: `printf "Uptime: %s\n" $UPTIME` invokes `printf` with many more than 2 arguments.  `printf "Uptime: %s\n" "$UPTIME"` runs `printf` with exactly 2 arguments.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the problem.